# do nothing when the image is not browsed

Tags: jquery

I want to prevent from opening popup,If image is not selected from browse input box.I have used return false and true ,I have also used e.preventDefault() but it also dosent worked for me.
Please check below code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Popup Box DIV </title>
<script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.resizecrop-1.0.3.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready( function() {
   $(".uploadphoto").click(function() {
       if(!$('.FieldRequired').val()){
           alert ('Empty value is not allowed');
    return false;
           }
           else{
return true;
        // When upload button is pressed, load the Popupbox First
        loadPopupBox();

        $('#popupBoxClose').click( function() {           
            unloadPopupBox();
        });

        $('#container').click( function() {
            unloadPopupBox();
        });

        function unloadPopupBox() {    // TO Unload the Popupbox
            $('#popup_box').fadeOut("slow");
            $("#container").css({ // this is just for style       
                "opacity": "1" 
            });
        }   

        function loadPopupBox() {    // To Load the Popupbox
            $('#popup_box').fadeIn("slow");
            $("#container").css({ // this is just for style
                "opacity": "1.5" 
            });        
        }    }   
    });

       });
</script>   
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {      
//$('.FieldRequired').attr('id','files');
// set up variables
var reader = new FileReader(),
    i=0,
    numFiles = 0,
    imageFiles;

// use the FileReader to read image i
function readFile() {
    reader.readAsDataURL(imageFiles[i])
}
// define function to be run when the File
// reader has finished reading the file
reader.onloadend = function(e) {

    // make an image and append it to the div
    var image = $('<img>').attr('src', e.target.result);
    var imgdiv = $('#popup_box');

    $(imgdiv).append(image);



    // if there are more files run the file reader again
    if (i < numFiles) {
        i++;
        readFile();
    }
};
$(".uploadphoto").click(function() {

    imageFiles = document.getElementById('files').files
    // get the number of files
    numFiles = imageFiles.length;
    readFile();           

});
});
</script> 
    <script>

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#popup_box img').resizecrop({
      width:40,
      height:60,
      vertical:"top"
    });  
  });  

</script>

</head>
<body><input type="file" value="" size="" class="Textbox FieldRequired" name="ProductFields[3]" id="files">
<input type="submit" value="upload" class="uploadphoto"/>
<div id="popup_box">    <!-- OUR PopupBox DIV-->

    <a id="popupBoxClose">close</a>   
</div>
<div id="container"> <!-- Main Page -->
    <h1>sample</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html> 
<style type="text/css">
/* popup_box DIV-Styles*/
#popup_box {
    display:none; /* Hide the DIV */
    position:fixed;  
    _position:absolute; /* hack for internet explorer 6 */  
    height:600px;  
    width:600px;  
    background:#FFFFFF;  
    left: 300px;
    top: 150px;
    z-index:100; /* Layering ( on-top of others), if you have lots of layers: I just maximized, you can change it yourself */
    margin-left: 15px;  

    /* additional features, can be omitted */
    border:2px solid #ff0000;      
    padding:15px;  
    font-size:15px;  
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ff0000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ff0000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ff0000;

}
#popup_box img{ height:600px; width:600px}
#container {
    background: #d2d2d2; /*Sample*/
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

a{ 
cursor: pointer; 
text-decoration:none; 
}

/* This is for the positioning of the Close Link */
#popupBoxClose {
    background: url("/close.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    color: transparent;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 26px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -28px;
    top: -14px;
}
</style>
```

Please check this http://jsfiddle.net/UmJtB/5/ for more understanding.I want to open popup only if I have selected any image.

Comment: @PSL Yes.and one alert message should there for selecting image.

Comment: @PSL alert("Please select any image");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$(".uploadphoto").click(function() {
  if(document.getElementById('files').files.length == 0) 
{
alert('Select an Image first');
return false;
} else {
    loadPopupBox();
}
```